# Not able to run the build of vb.net applicaition created in visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, build

I have developed a desktop application in vb.net using visual - studio 2010.

I want to run that application in different pc every time. For that I have created a build of that application.

But I am not able to run this application other than my pc.

I also installed the dot net framework 4.0 in other pc but it gives error "WIC component not installed".

What should I do to run my application in different computer systems every time?  , what are the pr-requisites for running the application.?

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Googling](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=WIC%20component%20not%20installed) that error would seem to suggest you need to install the Windows Imaging Components on the other machines.

[64 bit downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1385)

[32 bit downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=32)

Judging the by the system requirements I'm guessing Windows 7 onwards includes this by default.

> Supported Operating Systems:
>
> - Windows Server 2003
> - Windows Server 2003 R2 Datacenter Edition (32-Bit x86)
> - Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition (32-Bit x86)
> - Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition (32-bit x86)
> - Windows XP Service Pack 2
> - Windows XP SP2
> - Windows
>     Server 2003